# C# generic, where T class : (inheritance class)

Tags: c#, inheritance, data-structures, generic-list

I have two type of nodes, one is MyLinkNode it's used as base, another one is GraphNode which inheritance MyLinkNode.

I try to create MyQueue with MyLinkNode. Everything is OK until I try to add GraphNode to MyQueue. I can't use MyQueue with GraphNode since it's bigger.

An alternative way is create another queue for GraphNode, but that means I would need to create lots of class if I have more type of nodes.
Is there any suggestion?

```
public class MyQueue<T> where T : MyLinkNode<T> 
{
    private T Head;
    private T Last;
    public MyQueue(){ ... }
    public void Enqueue(T item)
    {
        item.Prev = Last;
        Last.Next = item;
        Last = item;
    }
}
public class MyGraphQueue
{   
    //everything is the same with MyQueue besides the Node Type
    //I don't want to create like this.
    private GraphNode Head;
    private GraphNode Last;
    public MyGraphQueue(){ ... }
    public void Enqueue(GraphNode item)
    {
        item.Prev = Last;
        Last.Next = item;
        Last = item;
    }
}
public class MyLinkNode<T>
{
    public T data { get; set; }
    public MyLinkNode<T> Next { get; set; }
    public MyLinkNode<T> Prev { get; set; }
}
public class GraphNode<T> : MyLinkNode<T>
{
    public GraphNode()
    {
        this.adjacencyNodes = new List<GraphNode<T>>();
        this.isVisited = false;
    }

    public List<GraphNode<T>> adjacencyNodes;
    public bool isVisited { get; set; }
}
public void BFS<T>(GraphNode<T> v)
{
    MyQueue<GraphNode<T>> queue = new MyQueue<GraphNode<T>>(); // error, can't implicit convert GraphNode to MyLinkNode<T>
    MyGraphQueue queue = new MyGraphQueue(); //It's how I do now.

 }
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "can't use MyQueue with GraphNode since it's bigger."

Comment: sorry for my poor explanation. If I use MyQueue with GraphNode the compiler would say it's illegal because GraphNode can't implicit convert to MyLinkNode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard Generics inheritance problem. You need to separate what the Queue needs from the generic type. Just add another base class for the queue constraint.

This will keep the queue to have the guarantee of all items having type T and not require extra types or multiple class definitions for all of the concrete types. Eric Lippert has a good article [here](https://ericlippert.com/2015/10/14/casts-and-type-parameters-do-not-mix/) on why this limitation was required in the generics system.

```
 public class CallingClass
{
    public void BFS(GraphNode v)
    {
        MyQueue<GraphNode> queue = new MyQueue<GraphNode>(); // error, can't implicit convert GraphNode to MyLinkNode<T>
       // MyGraphQueue queue = new MyGraphQueue(); //It's how I do now.

    }
}
public class QueueItem
{
    public QueueItem Next { get; set; }
    public QueueItem Prev { get; set; }
}

public class MyQueue<T> where T : QueueItem
{
    private T Head;
    private T Last;
    public MyQueue() {  }
    public void Enqueue(T item)
    {
        item.Prev = Last;
        Last.Next = item;
        Last = item;
    }
}

public class MyLinkNode<T>: QueueItem
{
    public T data { get; set; }

}
public class GraphNode : MyLinkNode<string>
{
    public GraphNode()
    {
        this.adjacencyNodes = new List<GraphNode>();
        this.isVisited = false;
    }

    public List<GraphNode> adjacencyNodes;
    public bool isVisited { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`MyQueue<T> where T : MyLinkNode<T>` cannot accept a `MyLinkNode<string>`

Beacuse here `T` is string. but, obviously `string` doesn't inherit from `MyLinkNode`

I think the solution is simpler than you imagine.

Just set the type (`T`) of the value in the queue, and inside use `MyLinkNode<T>`:

```
public class MyQueue<T> 
{
    private MyLinkNode<T> Head;
    private MyLinkNode<T> Last;

    public void Enqueue(MyLinkNode<T> item)
    {
        item.Prev = Last;
        Last.Next = item;
        Last = item;
    }
}

public void BFS(GraphNode v)
{
    MyQueue<string> queue = new MyQueue<string>(); // no error anymore
    queue.Enqueue(v);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not surprising.  You need

```
public class MyQueue<T, S> where T : MyLinkNode<S>
{
    private T Head;
    private T Last;
    public MyQueue() {  }
    public void Enqueue(T item)
    {
        item.Prev = Last;
        Last.Next = item;
        Last = item;
    }
}

public void BFS(GraphNode v)
{
    MyQueue<GraphNode, string> queue = new MyQueue<GraphNode, string>(); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is coming from your first line.

Use:

```
public class MyQueue<T> where T : MyLinkNode<string> { }
```

Instead of:

```
public class MyQueue<T> where T  : MyLinkNode<T> { }
```

and it will work fine.